# Android : Keep socket open to read message from server

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm working on an Android application that

- First, I have to connect to hardware server via TCP socket
- After connected, I will have to send *99*1## to server, then server will response with "*#*1##*#*1##"
- Then, I need to keep this socket alive and read incoming message
- After this point, server can send me message from times to times. But, When will message sent or length of message are undetermined.
- Every message will end with '##', For example, *1*1*18##, *1*0*19##, *1*1*#4*11## and else.
- When client (this app) receive message, it will notify activity to update UI.

So, I create a thread subclass to do this

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    public interface OnReadListener {
        public void onRead(ServerThread serverThread, String response);
    }

    Socket socket;
    String address;
    int port;
    OnReadListener listener = null;

    public ServerThread(String address, int port) {
        this.address = address;
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(address), port);

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(bw, true);
            writer.println("*99*1##");
            writer.flush();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while (!socket.isConnected() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                line = br.readLine();

                if (line != null) {
                    Log.i("Dev", "Line ")

                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onRead(this, line);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setListener(OnReadListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

And in the activity, I do it like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ServerThread st = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        startMonitoring();

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        stopMonitoring();

        super.onPause();
    }

    private void startMonitoring() {
        stopMonitoring();

        st = new ServerThread(SERVER_IP_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
        st.setListener(new OnReadListener{
            @Override
            public void onRead(ServerThread serverThread, String response) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // update UI or do something with response
                    }
                })
            }
        });
        st.start();
    }

    private void stopMonitoring() {
        if (st != null) {
            st.stop();
            st = null;
        }
    }
}
```

After I start this activity, I found that

- The message "*99*1##" has been send to server, I can see this message from server hardware.
- But, I only got first line of response from server '*#*1##*#*1##'
- After that, socket is still connected (stacktrace not printed) but I never got any further message from server. Listener never gets called.

I have no idea how to make this work. Any suggestion are welcome.

**Some note you might need to know**

I'm not quit sure that BufferReader is the right object I need for the job or not. Because when it failed to read, it will return null and the loop will keep running. I might need some object that can freeze the thread waiting for input. This object can wait for input as long as it takes since the server may send message in seconds, minutes, hours or more. Once message has received, the continue to execute the code and go to the next round of loop.

(I'm full-time iOS Dev, not really familiar with Java)

**Final Edit**

After I carefully check the code, I found the silly mistake I made

```
writer.println("*99*1##")
```

Basically, println will send "*99*1##" and then follow with **newline**. But my hardware server doesn't like that so it terminate the connection. That's why I got null from BufferReader's readLine().

After I change to

```
writer.print("*99*1##")
```

The server receive "*99*1##" and keep connection. Then, and I can loop to read response just like EJP suggest again

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onRead(this, line);
    }
}

if (listener != null) {
    listener.onTerminated(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (!socket.isConnected() ...
```

The problem is here. The test is pointless anyway, as it will never be false, but negating it means that the controlled block will never execute. Just remove the `isConnected()` test.

> when it failed to read, it will return null and the loop will keep running.

Because you didn't handle that case correctly. If `line` is null you must exit the loop and close the connection. The usual way to write that is:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Your sleep in your loop is just literally a waste of time.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But, may I ask if there is a way to open a socket, waiting for incoming message from server without having to loop? Because how this hardware was designed (not by me), I have to connect to socket and leave it connected. Once something happen on the hardware side, server will notify external device via this connected socket. I successfully did this years ago with Objective-C but stuck here in Java.

Comment: Any approach is welcome because I believe that the BufferReader may not be the right tool for this. But I just don't familiar with Java that much : |

Comment: The approach is to loop while `readLine()` doesn't return null. There are hundreds of examples of it here.

Comment: There is one point in the question, I have to maintain the connection between the socket and server open for message. The message could arrive right away, 5 mins or half a day later after socket connected to server. So, If I do like what you said, when I connected, readLine() will return *#*1##*#*1## and then null, then exit the loop and disconnect before I received any message. And if I reconnect, it will be just the same (connected, receive first message, disconnect). Is there anyway to keep socket open, hold the thread until there is something in the InputStream or server send something?

Comment: So you have to implement the appoication protocol, whatever it is. Loop until you've read a complet reply, and then stop reading. Only you can know exactly what this involves, as only you know what your application protocol is.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, I'm appreciate your help (Thank you). But, I wasn't the one who design the server hardware so I can't change the way it works. An Italian company create this hardware and protocol and I can only follow. They said that "I have to connect to server using TCP socket, then write *99*1## and keep this socket open. When something happen on their hardware side (for example, light bulb turn on), server will write back to the connected socket.

Comment: Nobody is blaming you for the protocol, but you have to implement it, and if you think that's an adequate protocol description you're mistaken.

Comment: Hi, after I carefully check my code, I found the mistake. It has nothing to do with the way to read response and your answer was already correct. So I upvote and select it as a correct answer. See my edited question for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while (isRunning) {
            line = br.readLine();

            if (line != null) {
                Log.i("Dev", "Line ")

                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onRead(this, line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Note: isRunning is a boolean variable to control your thread life cycle. Whenever you want to stop this thread, set `isRunning = false` and call `close()` on your connection.

If you want to create a TCP server you should use `ServerSocket` instead `Socket`. Here is java document about `socket` but android use the same http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/